# Having problems with installing composer in Xampp

Tags: php, composer-php

today i decided to start working with larvel so i started installing composer 
and when i tried to composer it gave me a error of

**php.exe-System Error**

```html
the program can't start because php5.dll is missing from your 
computer.Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem
```

So i looked up in some sites and blogs and some pointed out that by renaming or removing php.ini will solve the problem .so i gave that a try (Renamed it php_old.ini) and the error was cleared...but during installation there was a new error that appeared called

**Composer Download Error**

```html
Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are impossible.
If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl
```

So seeing it i changed back my php.ini file to its original filename and dont know what to do next 
im currently using Xampp and there was alot of posts regarding wamp composer installation which didn't help

So Could someone give me instruction  in installing the composer tool ..
it would be a great help 
thanks in advance